# Customizing (text) color of UIDatePicker in iOS 14 compat style

Tags: ios, uikit, uidatepicker

I am currently dealing with the `UIDatePicker` from `UIKit` on iOS 14. I am using the compact style:

| Picture (1) | Picture (2) |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

My question is: how can I customize the colours? Firstly the text colour of the text block shown in the picture (1) and secondly the "accent" colour in the picture (2).
Or: "how to change the blue colour to another colour?"

I have looked through so many SO questions but they all are for the wheel spinner `UIDatePicker` style.
Apple's documentation doesn't give any hint on that.

*Note*: I am integrating that in react native. I am not an iOS developer, and I am looking into the code of a library. If you need code snippets please say so and I will try to add them.

So, thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi, were you able to find a solution for this? I am also using a compact style and not able to modify the text color on uidatepicker.

Comment: unfortunately no, not yet

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for the same flexibility as I've got a background colour that's conflicting with both the `.compact` and `.inline` styles of `UIDatePicker`.

Setting the `tintColor` on the `UIDatePicker` will override what the blue accent colour is in your images, though that doesn't actually help my situation much. In the `.compact` style I get the text in black until it's selected, which isn't good for my background colour.